# Debugging Yii application model and controller

Tags: php, oop, debugging, model-view-controller, yii

I have a problem with debugging models, and controllers for yii 1.1. I use eclipse and xdebug as my tools. The problem is that I can't step into an example controller like "sitecontroller", I only see the object created, the same is true for the models. Is there a specific way to debug this, I usually use breakpoints, and start at the entry script. Also, am new to yii and the mvc pattern, I am trying to understand an old application, and that is why am not learning yii2 at the moment.

Comment: I use xdebug with netbeans and there are no problem using step by step or breakpoint ..

Comment: Are you able to step into a base controller, and not just CController. Also, where are you putting your breakpoints? Thanks.

Comment: Is possible follow the code sequence in each part of code  executed . if this is from a class too .. i place my breakpoint at the beginning of the code a i want inspect .

Comment: I have done some tests, and am making some improvements. What I changed is that I run the debugger and I go to index.php and place my breakpoint like you suggested, and then go to that page which triggers the debugger. I have only been able to do that with the views, and not with the models, and controllers.

Comment: I normally can place the breakpoint  in controller action code and in model function  and tipically i look at vars content  in the proper tabs .. anyway seems some step in  right direction

Comment: I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: So I have tried what you said, and I just realized that controllers are action based like you said, and thus will not trigger if the action is not run. for example, I have placed a breakpoint in the site login action, and then went to login in the view which then triggered the breakpoint which was awesome. I still am trying to figure out how to do the same with the model.

Comment: is simple  .. try to invoke eg a static function in you controller  .. place you breakpoint on the function call and follow step by step the execution .. or place the breakpoint on the firts instuction inside the static function ..

Comment: Thanks I will try that.